# Can't read former internal hdd file system via usb (fedora volume group name conflict)

Tags: linux, fedora, filesystems, partition, hard-disk

I took a hdd out of my fedora 25 laptop to replace with SSD.  The old drive is in an enclosure now.  I plug it in via USB and it mounts and is identified correctly as a 1TB total capacity drive.  However I do not see the file system.

All I do see are
- some files with names like config-.fc25.x86_64
- initramfs* files
- System.map-* files
- vmlinuz-* files
- efi folder (empty)
- extlinux folder
- grub2 folder
- lost+found folder

Is there something I can do to try to regain access to the file system?

Sorry if the information is minimal.  If more is needed please ask.

Current system is also Fedora 25.  thx

more info

```
[w@localhost]$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/external
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

[w@localhost]$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 11DCAA00-67D7-4922-AFA6-80642872E288

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048     411647     409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2   411648    2508799    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
**/dev/sdb3  2508800 1953523711 1951014912 930.3G Linux LVM**
```

So I have a logical volume.  Okay to get the name of the volume group

```
[w@localhost]$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  fedora lvm2 a--  231.88g    0 
  /dev/sdb3  fedora lvm2 a--  930.31g    0
```

and here is my problem (or at least what I am not sure how to deal with).  The VG on my root is named 'fedora' as is the VG on my old hdd.  So I am stuck here...

```
[w@localhost]$ sudo lvdisplay fedora
  Multiple VGs found with the same name: skipping fedora
  Use --select vg_uuid=<uuid> in place of the VG name.
```

*IF* the VGs did not have the same name I would get the logical volume names (which are quite likely 'home' and 'root') and mount the 'home' volume.

But how to I specify the fedora/home on my external drive sbd3 and NOT fedora/home on sda2?  thx

UPDATE2:
The first entry must be the external drive because of the size.  But is there any other way to determine that?

```
[w@localhost]$ sudo vgdisplay

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               930.31 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238160
  Alloc PE / Size       238160 / 930.31 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               fzDOdF-o2t6-jlLj-z777-hjzh-PpoR-ehoeM1

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               231.88 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              59362
  Alloc PE / Size       59362 / 231.88 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               RJFPw2-y9B8-PoqX-llVN-eo5y-1Avm-efmNd3
```

Once I have a VG UUID what can I do with this?  thx

Comment: Those look like boot partition files. Can you see if there are there are other partitions on the drive, using Disks or `parted` or your preferred partition management tool?

Comment: good idea.  the drive has 3 partitions

P1 - 210MB FAT
P2 - 1.1GB Ext4 - this is what mounts automatically
P3 - 999GB LVM2 Phyiscal Partition Linux LVM - in Disks there is no option to mount this partition.  I am not familiar with this kind of partition.  ideas?  thx

Comment: You would need to identify and mount the partition that has the data. What host OS are you trying to view it on? And what DE, if Linux? Automounting is configurable but may not deal with partitions beyond the first.

Comment: i finished my above answer.  please read that for partition info.  i am trying mount this on a Fedora 25 machine running GNOME.

Comment: Ah, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29 Logical Volume Manager. That might require more knowledge that I have. Suggest you edit the partition details into the question

Comment: I updated the OP.  You already did great getting me this far

Comment: Next step is to get your `VG UUID`.... Try `sudo vgdisplay`.

Comment: Got it and updated OP.  That looks useful, how do I use the VG UUID now?  thx

Comment: You could read some man pages, or maybe [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333914/two-physical-disks-with-same-volume-group-names-preventing-access) will help you.